# rtf (rich text format) base64 data display on angular 6 html

Tags: html, angular, angular6, embed, rtf

I have RTF file base64 code and I want to display it in my html. 
my angular ts file having below code

```
  this.display= 
 this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('data:application/rtf;base64,' 
 +'mybase64code')
```

and my html

```
<object [data]="display"></object>
```

when run the app showing "this Plug-in not supported". Please help me what is the wrong with this approach.

Comment: Can you solve your problem?, I have the same it.